# How to keep indexes performant on Sql Server table frequently updated (delete/insert) by batch process

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, indexing, etl

We have a table in our sql server database which holds 'today's' data and is updated by many scheduled jobs around the clock. Each job deletes rows it previously inserted and inserts new rows. The table data is also made available via a web site which runs many queries against it. The problem is the indexes are constantly fragmented and although it only has 1.5m rows querys are generally very slow and the website times out frequently.

So I would like to know if anyone else has experienced a similar scenario and if so how did you deal with it.

Comment: How often do you rebuild the indexes? Have you tried to create filtered indexes?

Comment: @Vladimir There is a scheduled maintenance job that updates stats once a week. However, the indexes are fragmented on a daily basis. Don't know much about filtered indexes so will investigate.

Comment: if indexes get fragmented enough each day why not modify job to do it every night or whenever slow time is? as far as filtered indexes, it is an index that has `where clause` that allows you to exclude or to include a specific subset of data, sometimes it is possible to only focus on data you need that is not fragmented as often.

Comment: Fragmentation is highly unlikely to be the cause of your website queries timing out. It only makes any difference if the table is not in cache and must be read from disc and only to large sequential scans of the table. The cause of the timeouts could be poor execution plans or just blocking from the concurrent data modifications on the table. Look at the wait stats.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ReOrg the indexes on a daily basis. Here's am image of a defrag job from SSMS:

[image]